# Работа с ListView

Tags: php, yii2

Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы при отсутствии элементов в списке ничего не выводилось совсем? Да, знаю там есть свойство emptyText, но даже с ним выводится тэг который указан в свойстве options (контейнер самого списка), а мне он не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить:

```
'options' => ['tag' => false],
'emptyText' => false
```

Смотрите исходник:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/BaseListView.php#L178

Comment: Я уже пробовал это. Не помогает. Тэг контейнера все равно отображается. Если посмотреть исходник еще ниже и найти [вызов](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/BaseListView.php#L140) этого метода то видно что тэг выводится, но с пустым контентом.

Comment: Да, верно, общий тег всего контейнера остается. Но это тоже частично решаемый вопрос. Можно воспользоваться тем, что если в `Html::tag()` передать `false`, то контент в тег заворачиваться не будет. Дополнил ответ. Но тогда и при наличии данных контейнерного тега не будет также. Альтернативный вариант -
 переопределить ListView, и реализовать этот момент по своему.